# How to segregate a string into percentage component and normal text in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a string like

```
73 % polyester, 20 % modacrylic, 7 % cotton
```

there should be 3 rows with 2 columns:

| Percentage | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 73 | polyester |
| 20 | modacrylic |
| 7 | cotton |

```
5,5% cotton, 20% modacrylic, 74,5 % polyester, min. 90 % recycled material
```

Output should have 3 rows:

| Percentage | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 5,5 | cotton |
| 20 | modacrylic |
| 74,5 | polyester |

If a string doesn't start with a numeric character then by default the Percentage Column should get value as 100 and component should get all the characters before Comma (',')

e.g.

```
Polyester fibre , 150 g/sq.m.
```

| Percentage | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Polyester fibre |

I have written following logic but it's not working as expected:

```
SELECT
       a.item_no,
       a.item_type,
       a.code_sup,
       a.type_sup,
       a.from_dtime,
       a.id,
       a.material_name,
       a.str AS component,
       b.str AS percentage
FROM
       ( SELECT
                item_no,
                item_type,
                code_sup,
                type_sup,
                from_dtime,
                id,
                material_name,
                level rowseq,
                regexp_substr(str,'[^/]+',1,ROWNUM) str
         FROM
                ( SELECT
                         '23456' item_no,
                         'PLASTIC' item_type,
                         '10121' code_sup,
                         'SUP' type_sup,
                         '27-Nov-2020' from_dtime,
                         '1.1' id,
                         '26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton' material_name,
                         level rowseq,
                         regexp_substr(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','% /','%/'),'[^%]+',1,ROWNUM) str
                   FROM
                        dual
                   CONNECT BY
                        level <= regexp_count('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','[^%]+')
                 )
         WHERE
                 rowseq = 1
         CONNECT BY
                 level <= regexp_count(str,'[^/]+')     
       ) a,
       (
         SELECT
                item_no,
                item_type,
                code_sup,
                type_sup,
                from_dtime,
                id,
                material_name,
                ROWNUM rowseq,
                TRIM(regexp_substr(str,'[^/%]+',1,ROWNUM) ) str
         FROM
                ( SELECT
                         '23456' item_no,
                         'PLASTIC' item_type,
                         '10121' code_sup,
                         'SUP' type_sup,
                         '27-Nov-2020' from_dtime,
                         '1.1' id,
                         '26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton' material_name,
                         level rowseq,
                         regexp_substr(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','% /','%/'),'[^%]+',1,ROWNUM) str
                  FROM
                         dual
                         CONNECT BY
                         level <= regexp_count('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','[^%]+')
                 )
          WHERE
                 rowseq = 2
                 CONNECT BY
                 level <= regexp_count(str,'[^/%]+')
       ) b
WHERE  a.rowseq = b.rowseq
AND    a.str IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
       a.item_no,
       a.item_type,
       a.code_sup,
       a.type_sup,
       a.from_dtime,
       a.id ;
```

Here I am getting only 1 row with Percentage as 26,5 and Component as polyester , min. 90 , although I should get 2 rows

| Percentage | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 26,5 | polyester |
| 67 | cotton |

Please guide.

I have tried with this logic but its not working for a material name which is starting with a character , for which it should set a default percentage of 100

```
WITH parsed as(
    SELECT /*+ parallel(t,8) materialize */
    '80393904' item_no,
                    'ART' item_type,
                    '22025' bu_code_sup,
                    'SUP' bu_type_sup,
                    '27-FEB-2020' from_dtime,
                    1.4 id,
    'PPCO, grade 4 acc. to spec. AA-168522' material_name, 
    regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace('PPCO, grade 4 acc. to spec. AA-168522','%  ','% '),', ',','), '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'),'[^,]+',1,ROWNUM) 
    AS split_value
      FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace('PPCO, grade 4 acc. to spec. AA-168522','% /','%/'), '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'),'[^,]+')
)
,in_pairs as(
select /*+ parallel(k,8) materialize */
item_no,item_type,bu_code_sup,bu_type_sup,from_dtime,id,material_name
      ,regexp_substr(split_value, '[0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*') as percentage
      ,trim(substr(split_value, instr(split_value, '%') + 1)) as component
  from parsed k where split_value LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
)
select /*+ parallel(it,8) */
distinct item_no,item_type,bu_code_sup,bu_type_sup,from_dtime,id,material_name,percentage,component from in_pairs it
;
```

Comment: Normalize your database design, at least to 1NF. There shouldn't be more than a single value per column.

Comment: I don't see any solution to your problem. Your data is so unstructured that it makes it impossible to have a pattern. I mean, your colon is your decimal separator, your component separator and separates a component from a comment in your last example. This makes it impossible to know if "Polyester fibre , 150 g/sq.m" is 2 separate components or 1 component with a description to ignore.

Comment: What do you do with "10% air, 80% water, 10% fire, 100% recyclable" - how do you treat the last token? Does your query need to recognize which words or phrases are "materials", and which are "something else" (such as "recyclable", "made in Taiwan", etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your string transformation step-by-step and thoroughly.

1. Remove White space after comma and percent

```
replace(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','%  ','% '),', ',',')
```

2.Using "," instead of "%" as a string delimiter,

```
regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','%  ','% '),', ',','), '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'),'[^,]+',1,ROWNUM) str
```

3.Filter for both row 1 and 3 NOT JUST 1

```
    WHERE rowseq IN (1, 3)
```

4. NOT SURE why you need the nested query at line 13 and the join subquery "b" starting at line 46 (IT'S REDUNDUNT)
5. Do your component, percent split using the '%'

```
    REGEXP_REPLACE(a.str, '^(\d+.*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\3') AS component,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(a.str, '^(\d+.*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\1') AS percentage
```

And you will get..

```
SELECT
                    a.item_no,
                    a.item_type,
                    a.code_sup,
                    a.type_sup,
                    a.from_dtime,
                    a.id,
                    a.material_name,
                    a.rowseq,
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(a.str, '^(\d+.*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\3') AS component,
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(a.str, '^(\d+.*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\1') AS percentage                    
                FROM
                    (  SELECT
                    '23456' item_no,
                    'PLASTIC' item_type,
                    '10121' code_sup,
                    'SUP' type_sup,
                    '27-Nov-2020' from_dtime,
                    '1.1' id,
                   '26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton' material_name,
                    level rowseq,
                    regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','%  ','% '),', ',','), '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'),'[^,]+',1,ROWNUM) str
                    
                FROM
                    dual
                CONNECT BY
                    level <= regexp_count(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace('26,5 % polyester, min. 90% recycled, 67 % cotton','% /','%/'), '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'),'[^,]+')
                         
                    ) a
                WHERE rowseq IN (1, 3)
                ORDER BY
                    a.item_no,
                    a.item_type,
                    a.code_sup,
                    a.type_sup,
                    a.from_dtime,
                    a.id ;
```

For more complicated scenarios and robust code do the following.
Of course you need to specify your transformation **RULES** carefully inside the **WITH** Clause, I'm Not a big fan of ***nested statements*** but the use case demands it.

```
var the_specification varchar2(500)
exec :the_specification := '5,5% cotton, 20% modacrylic, 74,5 % polyester, min. 90 % recycled material, Polyester fibre , 150 g/sq.m.'

WITH specstr as (
      SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(rndOne.refined_str, '%') THEN
              rndOne.refined_str
            ELSE  
              REGEXP_REPLACE(rndOne.refined_str, '(^[[:alnum:][:space:]]+),|,([[:alnum:][:space:]]+),|,([[:alnum:][:space:]]+$)', ',100% \1\2\3,',1,1) -- Add the default Percentage Column '100%'
            END AS refined_str
      FROM(
            SELECT
               REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                     REGEXP_REPLACE( 
                        REGEXP_REPLACE(
                           REGEXP_REPLACE(
                              REGEXP_REPLACE(:the_specification,'\s*%','% '), -- remove white space tagging the percentage'%' sign
                            '(\d+),(\d+)', '\1.\2'), -- Replace dot'.' as decimal separator
                        '(,*[^,]*recycl[^,]*,*)', ','), -- remove any additonal comment THE_RULE: consider 'recycl' as comment
                      '\s{2,}', ' '), -- remove double white space
                  ',{2,}|\s,|,\s', ','), -- remove duplicate commas ',' or any trailing and tagging white space from comma
                '^,*|,*$', '') refined_str -- remove comma from the start and end                
              FROM DUAL
            )rndOne
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mtrl_ratio.str, '^(\d+,*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\1') Percentage,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(mtrl_ratio.str, '^(\d+,*\d*)(%)([^,]*)$','\3') Component
FROM (
  SELECT        
        level rowseq,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
          regexp_substr(
            specstr.refined_str
           ,'[^,]+',1,ROWNUM), -- split string using comma as delimiter
        '(\d+)\.(\d+)', '\1,\2') str -- Replace Back comma',' as decimal separator)
    FROM
        specstr
    CONNECT BY
        level <= regexp_count(
                  specstr.refined_str
                  ,'[^,]+')
)mtrl_ratio
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mtrl_ratio.str, '%')
```

Comment: Thanks Ammar , just one thing if a string is like Polyurethane foam, according to spec. AA-300, CMH then percentage should get 100 and component should be the first string before comma i.e. Polyurethane foam but here it is giving 2 rows with string split at comma .

Comment: Hi Radha, Consider the string "5,5% cotton, 20% modacrylic, 74,5 % polyester, min. 90 % recycled material, Polyester fibre , 150 g/sq.m,  Polyurethane foam, according to spec. AA-300, CMH", Do you have a case where such string could occur and if so what would be the out put.

Comment: the material composition can be in any form , we need to just extract components out of it which have % in them and in that case also one part should begin with a numeric character then only that component is considered , here min 90% is to be considered , polyester fibre is also not considered because we have components with different percentage but the only exception is if a material composition doesn't start with a numeric then we need to set default percentage as 100 and component as the entire part before comma , so if string is polyester fibre , then 100 | Polyester fibre will be Output

Comment: The nested query inside WITH clause should fix your problems..

Comment: Hey @radha, How do you find the solution?

Comment: I tried running the WITH Clause on the specified input but I didn't get the desired output . comma was not replaced with dot , in addition I didn't get 90% recycled material as well , I am getting 5,5   20   & 74 ,5 in percentage column , where output rows for percentage column  should have been 5.5   , 20 , 74.5  ,  90

Comment: I have pasted the modified code , plz check its not working for string starting with a character , rest its working fine

Comment: Hi radha, your original question seems to suggest you need comma as a decimal indicator not a dot, and "recycled material" should not be included in the final result. Line # 19, 36 does exactly that, If you modify the code accordingly you can get what you want.

Comment: As for the string "Starting with a character" could you give me an instance you are working with and I'll see to it.

Comment: The last code snippet which I shared , its working fine if I have 90% recycled .                            The input string sample where material name starts with a character  is PPCO, grade 1 acc. to spec. AA-160 , here in the Output I should only get PPCO in component column and default percentage 100 in the Percentage output column .

Comment: Hi radha I tried your string and the output I'm getting is [exactly as you want](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65033437ffa5063300386cd954769c19) , could you pls copy the code again and try. I'm not sure what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your string as a csv then there is a way to split the elements from csv string and extract percentage and component. Comments inside code:

```
Select
    TRIM(SubStr(COL1, 1, InStr(COL1, '%') - 1)) "PERCENTAGE",
    TRIM(SubStr(COL1, InStr(COL1, '%') + 1)) "COMPONENT"
FROM
    (
        SELECT  
            COL1
        FROM    
            (   
                SELECT 
                    INDX, 
                    MY_STR1, 
                    COL1_ELEMENTS, 
                    CASE WHEN SubStr(TRIM(COL1), 1, 1) IN('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') THEN COL1 ELSE '100 % ' || COL1 END "COL1"
                FROM    
                    (   
                        SELECT 
                            0 "INDX", 
                            COL1 "MY_STR1", 
                            COL1_ELEMENTS "COL1_ELEMENTS", 
                            COL1 "COL1"
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                  REPLACE(COL1, DELIMITER || ' ', DELIMITER) "COL1",    
                                  Trim(Length(Replace(COL1, DELIMITER || ' ', DELIMITER))) - Trim(Length(Translate(REPLACE(COL1, DELIMITER || ' ', DELIMITER), 'A' || DELIMITER, 'A'))) + 1 "COL1_ELEMENTS"
                                FROM (SELECT 
                                        '73 % polyester, 20 % modacrylic, something else, 67 % cotton' "COL1", ',' "DELIMITER" -- here comes your string and delimiter, if delimiter is not comma (,) then you should replace ',' with your delimiter in RULES clause
                                      FROM DUAL)        
                            )
                    )
                MODEL       
                    DIMENSION BY(0 as INDX)
                    MEASURES(COL1, COL1_ELEMENTS, CAST('a' as VarChar2(4000)) as MY_STR1)
                    RULES ITERATE (10)      --UNTIL (ITERATION_NUMBER <= COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1]) -- If you don't know the number of elements this should be bigger then you aproximation. Othewrwise it will split given number of elements
                    (
                        COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = COL1_ELEMENTS[0],
                        MY_STR1[0] = COL1[CV()],
                        MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], ',', 1) + Length(',')),
                        COL1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], 1, CASE WHEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], ',') <> 0 THEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], ',')-1 ELSE Length(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER]) END)
                    )
            )
        WHERE INDX > 0 And INDX <= COL1_ELEMENTS
    )
--
-- Result:
--
-- PERCENTAGE   COMPONENT
-- 73           polyester
-- 20           modacrylic
-- 100          something else
-- 67           cotton
```

Comment: Inserted into your string new component "something else" to test inserting 100% if there is no starting number. Regards...

Comment: One other thing - make sure that decimal character is not the same as delimiter...